# Zeros of polynomials algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ be polynomials in $F[x]$, where $F$ is any field. If $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ have no common zeros, then they are relatively prime.

Comment: is this true or false?

Answer (score 1):

No... if the polynomials have a common factor that doesn't have roots in the field, they aren't relatively prime but have no common roots.

Answer (score 1):

Counterexample:

In $\mathbb{R}$, the functions $f(x)=1+x+x^2+x^3$ and $g(x)=1-x+x^2-x^3$ have no common root, despite both having one root in $\mathbb{R}$, yet they have the common factor $1+x^2$.

Answer (score 0):

It is true if $F$ is algebraically closed. If not, it fails, since then there is a nonconstant polyhomial $f$ with no roots in $F$, so ditto for $g = f^n$, but they are not coprime.